# Setup logging before importing other modules

Tags: python, logging

What is the standard way for setting up the logging system (formatting, level), *before* modules are imported?

The reason I want to do this is that during the import phase complex data structures are loaded, and progress is shown with loggers. But since the logging level is not set, I do not even see those log entries (level is by default `WARNING`)

I could do a hack like this:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(...)

import mymodule
```

But I do not like running code before importing stuff.

Isn't there an accepted way to "pre-configure" the logging system from outside the application, with env variables or any such alternative? Something like:

```
LOG_LEVEL=INFO LOG_FORMAT="..." python main.py
```

I can of course evaluate those env vars myself (and at that point my hack above is good enough), but I would like to reuse existing ideas before implementing my own solution.

Comment: If you don't like running code before importing stuff, then why does `mymodule` load complex data structures at import time?  Usually library modules just declare a bunch of stuff (`def`, `class`, maybe some global attributes) and don't do any heavy work at import time.

Comment: @wim loading and parsing data files, with constant data, which will be used throughout the application lifetime. For each separate module, no operations are done before the imports in that module. Obviously, importing that module will run the operations at the global level

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to pre-configure the logging system with a different default behavior. Best practice is to avoid configuring logging at import time - it is up to the user to decide the appropriate log level and where the logs should go to (if anywhere). For the logging configuration to be, well, *configurable* it needs to be delayed until the entry-point of your application rather than eagerly configured at import time.

The library code (`mymodule`) should not assume that there is a terminal that somebody is watching for output, or even that there is a writable filesystem available for a log file.

I would recommend this pattern:

```
# main.py
import logging
import mymodule

def main():
    # parse cmdline args here
    logging.basicConfig(...)
    # or logging.config.fileConfig
    # or logging.config.dictConfig
    mymodule.init()
    # do work here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And in the library code:

```
# mymodule.py
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def init():
    log.info("loading complex data structures...")
```

This avoids dropping the initialization log events on the floor, but there is another benefit to an explicit init call in the library code: the dataset for initialization can be configurable, via arguments to `init()` or a user-provided config file. This means during testing you can load from a smaller scaled-down dataset, so that the test suite does not run slowly.

Comment: Maybe even better to put all your module logic in a class and do it on instantiation?

Comment: Not answering the question. This answer implement (and over-engineer) what is both literally stated in question ("I could do a hack like this:...") and explained why is not desired.

Comment: @stam You're totally missing the point. The part stated in the question which was hacky was that logging was configured _before_ the `import mymodule` executed. Doing so is problematic - it should be possible to import a library without it configuring the logging system, and all imports should be at the top so that dependencies are resolved upfront. Look at any well maintained project and you will see the same pattern, logging is not configured at import time but delayed until the entry-point.

Comment: I can very well be missing smt here. What I see is the question "What is the way for setting up the logging system *before* modules are imported?" and the answer that *first imports* module and *only afterwards* sets logging. Possible use case is described by OP - module directly executes expensive code (thus is executed on module import time), and user wants to see that code execution progress reported in logs. I.e. one does not desire to configure logging inside imported module, but rather configure logging first (set formatting, level...) and have - if any - module logging follow that.

Comment: @stam I see. I think the actual problem there is execution of some expensive code done eagerly at import time, it should be decoupled from the import itself. That way you're able to configure logging before doing work (loading and parsing data files) which might want to emit log events. An unconfigured logging system does not know what to do with log events (whether to emit them or not, where to send them etc) so the general pattern is like I've shown in the answer and is also as described in the [logging howto docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules).